# Broken bindings when using modal dialog in angular

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-scope

I am using the [ngModal](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngModal) modal dialog box directive for my angular application. It's displaying some weird behavior that I don't quite understand. When I attach variables directly to the controller's $scope and reference them in the dialog box, the binding breaks. Changing their values in the dialog has no effect on the variables in the controller. But if I add the variables as properties to an object and then add the object to the $scope it works. In other words, if I do this

```
$scope.v1 = 1
$scope.v2 = 'abc'
```

it doesn't work, but if I do

```
$scope.myData = {
   v1: 1,
   v2: 'abc'
}
```

things work fine. What's the deal? You can see a working version of the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ImmWTQtazwdiuXEQw8wo?p=preview) and a broken version [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1KxZm7nB7gpMw94a1AS3?p=preview).

If the plunk apps aren't loading for you, here is the code:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app='ngModalDemo'>
  <head>
    <title>ngQuickDate Demo</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-modal.css" media="all" />
    <style type='text/css'>
      body{font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif}
      h1 { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
      .ng-cloak { display: none; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller='DemoController'>
      <modal-dialog show='myData.modalShown' width='500px' dialog-title='Modal Dialog Title' on-close='logClose()'>
        <p>This is some html content</p>
        <p>
          <label for='hello'>Hello:</label>
          <input type='text' name='hello' ng-model='myData.hello' />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for='foo'>Foo:</label>
          <input type='text' name='foo' ng-model='myData.foo' />
        </p>
        <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg' width='300px'/>
      </modal-dialog>
      <button ng-click='toggleModal()'>Toggle Modal</button>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <p><strong>Shown?</strong> {{myData.modalShown}}</p>
      <p><strong>Hello</strong>: {{myData.hello}}</p>
      <p><strong>Foo</strong>: {{myData.foo}}</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-modal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

angular app

```
app.config(function(ngModalDefaultsProvider) {
    return ngModalDefaultsProvider.set({
        closeButtonHtml: "<i class='fa fa-times'></i>"
    });
});
```

angular controller

```
app = angular.module('ngModalDemo')

app.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {
      link: "http://google.com",
      modalShown: false,
      hello: 'world',
      foo: 'bar'
    }

    $scope.logClose = function() {
      console.log('close!');
    };
    $scope.toggleModal = function() {
      $scope.myData.modalShown = !$scope.myData.modalShown;
    };
});
```

Comment: When you use the object you are passing a pointer, when you pass the primitives you are passing values. When values change they don't point to anything, but when an object's attribute changes the pointer is updated.

Comment: Are strings considered primitive values?

Comment: Yes. Unless invoked with the String constructor. new String('abc').

Comment: can you post the html code where you are binding? I cannot get plunker to load.

Comment: I added the code. First time using plunker. They pull up for me okay, but maybe I did something wrong.